# Typesetting the Kvant journal mathematical problem book (Задачник «Кванта» по математике)

Tags: unicode, font-encodings

I've visited a colleague of mine, Karel Horák, a Czech TeXist, in Prague and he presented/gave me a nice TeX problem. He wishes to get PDF file from TeX file. It sounds easy!

Issues of the Kvant (*The Quant's mathematical problem book*) journal have been released publicly some time ago ([TeX](http://www.kvant.info/zkm_tex/zkm_main.tex), [PDF](http://www.kvant.info/zkm_tex/zkm_main.pdf), http://www.kvant.info/zkm_main.htm).

His first problem was which encoding the file is written in. He tried all the encodings in TeXworks with no luck. I've tried several automatic detection systems ([first site](http://i-tools.org/charset), [second site](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/)). They identified SJIS and UTF-8, that's wrong. I haven't tested [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet/2.2.1) package in Python (that's a sort of my ToDo).

I've tried different strategy. I wished to test all the encodings from the `iconv` program. I've created a standalone Lua script to do that for me. We run `texlua mal-split.lua`:

```
-- I'm mal-split.lua...
-- I test all encodings from iconv -l...

os.execute("iconv -l >list.txt")
content=io.lines("list.txt")
for line in content do
  for term in string.gmatch(line,"[^ ]+") do
  print("Processing "..term)
  command="iconv -f "..term.." -t UTF-8 zkm_main.tex >zkm_main-"..term..".tex"
  os.execute(command)
  end -- for term
end -- for line
```

Then I've tried to find some word from the PDF file (Copy+Paste) among those many TeX files. And that's it! The used encoding is probably one of these: `CP866`, `CP1125` or `CP1131`.

There are some other problems to get PDF file from that TeX file:

- We are missing all the figures, see the `\epsfbox` command. We need to download them somehow from the server (if they are present there) or extract them from the PDF file or accompanying HTML+PNG files. We guess some of them are created in Metapost. We can remove this problem by defining `\def\epsfbox#1{}` at the beginning of the file. I have neither found the necessary files with pictures nor font files. I used `wget -r -N http://www.kvant.info/` (2 GB). I wrote an email to the site administrator if they could provide them.

This is the reply to my humble request to get source codes of the figures:

```
  Hello, Pavel! I'm afraid the most of the data you requested is lost...
  It has been a long time since *.tex files were produced. It's a chance
  that you can find some pictures here
  http://www.kvant.info/zkm_main.htm
  Unfortunately it's not possible to contact the author of the files...
  С уважением,
  sergereal
```

The pictures loaded by the [HTML](http://www.kvant.info/zkm_main.htm) webpage (GIF, JPG, SWF) are located in the `/zkm_in/` folder, here they are:
http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/docasne/zkm_im.rar

- The file is missing the preamble, there should be some as there are undefined commands like `\LARGE`. I haven't found another TeX file(s) at that server.
- We probably should load some support package(s) as they are using Cyrillic letters in the command names. Or we need to change engine from `latex` to something else...
- The list of fonts from the PDF file is: jour10, scbbx10, scbex10, scbit10, scbmi10, scbr10, scbsy10 and T1 to T9.

**So the task is to reconstruct the preamble, that's my best guess.** I'm trying to reproduce the PDF file by compiling TeX file by any means necessary.

These are some TeX files converted [from CP866](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/docasne/zkm_main-CP866.rar), [from CP1125](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/docasne/zkm_main-CP1125.rar) and [from CP1131](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/docasne/zkm_main-CP1131.rar) to UTF-8 just in case you cannot run the iconv tool. I enclose a preview of the first page of the PDF file.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to write with Cyrillic letters? Usually I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T2A,OT1]{fontenc}`

Comment: I don't think the encoding is relevant; a macro file is surely needed that defines `\LARGE` and similar commands, plus the fonts.

Comment: ooh this question sounds very interesting! `:)`

Comment: Somewhat confused. You are trying to create a PDF which will look like a PDF you already have. Is that correct?

Comment: @cfr Yes, that's correct. I tried to help my colleague to reconstruct all the necessary source codes.

Comment: Why? Why do you need the source code for something like this? [Since it is a kind of archival usage, I take it that it is not because you want to modify the content, which is when lack of source is usually an issue.]

Comment: @cfr Please, don't waste your time on this question. That's not a big deal! We've solved most of the problems, the remaining problem are the graphs. He could use some vector+raster graphics from the website or he could extract portions of the original PDF files. My colleague wanted to retypeset and unify all the issues for some reason (probably to get a printable book for his library).

Comment: Could the encoding be a form of KOI8, such as KOI8-CS?

Answer (score 3):

I think, the first and absolutely necessary step is to get the original fonts back. Without the fonts, you cannot reproduce the line and page breaks or the overall look of the originals.

Looking at the name of the fonts, they are following a "Computer Modern" tradition, so they may be originally written in METAFONT or METAPOST and may still be luring on some server (ftp, listserv repository, gopher, ...) if you can't get them from backup tapes.

If you cannot find them, you can peel out the glyphs (letter shapes) from the pdf file (and, because the files are that old, you will probably get the full font in one try instead of getting overlapping subsets different for each pdf file). But the necessary tfm files are still missing ...

When you have them, measuring the page dimensions and making a trial document class for LaTeX is the next step. This is also more than just writing a preamble, but much more feasible than reconstructing lost fonts.